# Run script on startup not working if used with watch command

Tags: bash, unix, cron

I've a file called `/root/run.sh` in which following code has been wrote

```
/usr/bin/watch -n1 "echo hello >> /root/out.txt"
```

If I launch manually in terminal it in the following manner

```
bash /root/run.sh
```

all works fine.

Now I want that this file is called every time I start my os, so I modified the cronjob file through `crontab -e` and added the following line:

```
@reboot bash /root/run.sh
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, that means that after the reboot it doesn't write 'hello' in the `out.txt` file.

If I modify the `run.sh` script in the following manner:

```
echo hello >> /root/out.txt
```

then all works fine, that means after the reboot it writes one time the word 'hello' in the `out.txt` file.

How can I use the cronjob to execute a watch command?

Comment: Try specifying the full path to `watch`

Comment: @jordanm already tried but same problem. I updated my question

Comment: why do you want to use cron to run a watch command ? The purpose of watch is to show the results of a command full-screen and update continuously; if you're redirecting the output into a file and backgrounding it ( as you do using cron ) there's really no reason to use watch in the first place.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez It doesn't matter why I have to use the watch command with a cronjob through reboot. I just need it. The purpose of the watch command is to repeat a task every x seconds and where the output is done (on screen, file, ...) it doesn't matter. My cronjob has to start this script and you have to understand that this is a minimal example of my use case

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem writing `bash /root/run.sh` in the file located in `/etc/rc.local`. Now all works fine but I wonder why I can't put it in the cronjob list through `@reboot`